# How does Spring Integration "internal" messaging work?

Tags: spring-integration

Perhaps a silly question, but keep reading about SIs "lightweight messaging within Spring-based applications". I want to know how (if) SI uses messaging internally. When I run an SI (Boot) application (one that doesn't require AMPQ ... aka 'messaging' support), I don't have to run a Rabbit server. But, from what I gather, SI uses messaging internally. How is this accomplished? I can't seem to find any reference explaining this & what infrastructure is required to make this possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The messages are simply Java objects (`o.s.messaging.Message`) passed between components. No external broker is needed, unless you need persistence.

I suggest you read Mark Fisher's book (Spring Integration in Action) and/or the [reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/).

Answer (score 1):

The messaging inside spring integration are in-memory java objects passed from one service to another via channels/queue. It provides a mechanism to define the flow and order of processing, also allowing each service step to work in isolation. The spring integration queue is eventually an implementation of java.util.Queue interface. 
It is different from commercial Messaging tools like IBM MQ or Active MQ as it doesnt offer persistence. Which means if you kill the jvm or the app process is stopped, all the messages in flight on the Spring queue/channel are lost. A lot if times this is acceptable if the process in idempotent, i.e When the application comes up, I can restart the process from beginning.